# Why is this limit statement false?

Tags: calculus, limits

Determine whether the statement is true or false.

> If 
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{ 
> x→0} 
> f(x) =\infty \text { and }
> \lim_{x→0} g(x) = \infty, \text{ then } 
> \lim_{x→0}[f(x) − g(x)] = 0$.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: What do you think the answer is? What have you tried?

Comment: I was told the answer is false, but I don't understand why it's false.

Comment: Hint: what if we define $g(x) = f(x) + 1$?

Comment: Infinity is not an actual number. It only expresses that a function increases without bounds. Therefore you cannot evaluate $\infty - \infty$. Using Bungo's example of $g(x)=f(x)+1$ in the above comment $f(x)-g(x)=1$ for any value of $x$ despite the fact that the limits for both functions as $x \to \infty$ are $\infty$.

Comment: @patatahooligan - It might be useful to point out that the notation $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = \infty$ actually means something quite different from $\displaystyle\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} f(x) = c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. The latter indicates that $f(x)$ gets arbitrarily close to $c$ as $x$ approaches 0, whereas the former indicates that $f(x)$ grows unbounded as $x$ approaches $0$ (and is therefore arbitrarily close to nothing).

Answer (score 13):

As a counterexample, consider $f(x) = \frac{2}{x^2}$ and $g(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}$. Then:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0}g(x) = \infty
$$
but
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}[f(x) - g(x)] = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^2} = \infty \neq 0
$$

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand.

Comment: In my counterexample, the two hypotheses are satisfied, but the conclusion was violated.

Answer (score 2):

The difference $$\infty - \infty $$ is not defined.

So you can determine if this statement is true, if you know the functions $f$ and $g$, so that you can find the difference $f-g$, and then take the limit $x \rightarrow 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Since counterexamples have already been posted, there is no doubt that this statement is false. I will, however provide an intuitive explanation as to why.

$\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=\infty$ by definition means that f will continue to grow without bounds as x grows. Knowing that two functions $f$ and $g$ both approach infinity as x also approaches infinity does not give you any insight on the behavior of $f-g$. That is, because you do not know at which speed these two functions approach infinity. For example $f(x)=x^2$ increases in value much faster than $g(x)=x$ as $x$ increases. As a result,

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=\infty
$$

Conversely, if $g$ approaches infinity faster than $f$ does:

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=-\infty
$$

Lastly, if $f$ and $g$ approach infinity at the same speed then:

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}(f(x)-g(x))=c\in \mathbb{R}
$$

where $c$ will be their difference at $x \to \infty$.

You can infer which of the aforementioned cases is true by calculating the value of the limit

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}
$$

Look up L'Hôpital's rule if you don't know how to evaluate limits of the forms $\infty / \infty$ and $0/0$

Answer (score 0):

Consider how fast each moves towards infinity.  If the two functions move at different rates, then there will always be a difference.

Comment: So, because both limits approach 0 from infinity, they are equal. Therefore, subtracting g(x) from f(x) would be the equivalent of subtracting 0 from 0, which is 0... Am I getting that right? So, it's actually true...

Comment: That statement doesn't make sense. Infinity isn't a number so it's meaningless and incorrect to say that two infinities are 'equal'. Likewise, it's meaningless to perform normal arithmetic on $\infty$.

Comment: @AugustSepp Consider the journey, not the destination.  As 'x' changes, so does f(x) and g(x).  Imagine this change is two cars driving down a road, and each function represents how far they've gone.  If, and only if, they have the same starting point and the same rate of change (velocity/are going the same speed), will they be at the same point throughout their journey (the distance between them is 0).  If they are going difference speeds, eventually one will pass they other and then they will get farther and farther apart; there will always be a difference greater than zero.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the information provided is insufficient to tell that the above mentioned statement is true or false. 
Hope previous answers would have made you a clear idea about the question you have posted.
$ \infty $ is not a value, It is used to symbolize uncountably large number. It can also be meant as moving large number. when comes to finding limits, one has to know at what rate a function varies or tends to a limit.
The statement 
$$ \lim_{x \to 0} [f(x)- g(x)] =0 $$

is true only when the if statement of the question should be ( condition $\alpha$)
$$  \lim_{x \to 0} f(x) =\lim_{x \to 0} g(x) $$ or $$ f(x)= g(x) ,  \forall  x  \epsilon  R$$

but this cannot be inferred from if statements provided above, because it will lead to an assumption that $$ \infty - \infty =0 $$ but $$ \infty -\infty $$ is undefined. 
  For the statement to be true, you have to look for the equation(reframing condition $\alpha$) $$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =1 $$
Hence, The statement can be true with your if statements only if the functions f(x) and g(x) are either $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{sin(x)}$ or vice versa respectively. In a generalized form or in the form of well defined functions, the statement is false.